# Specific CSV Read Filtering

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I am pretty new to Python, so I am possibly looking over an easy solution, but everything I have tried thus far has been fruitless.

I have hundreds of CSV files with identical format. The format I have is

--Name of File (unimportant)

--Single Number Value (unimportant)

--**Important Row of Column Names**

--Two More Rows of Unimportant Formatting Garbage

--**Thousands of Rows of Important Data**

--Several Blank Rows

--Thousands of Rows of Unimportant Garbage Again

I need to format it so that I am able to easily grab the Column Names and the Important Data underneath. The format is set so that the column names are always on row 5 and that the data always starts on row 8, but the amount of data can very from several hundred to several thousand.

EDIT: I got the exact row number of the heading wrong. Also, I forgot to mention that I need to save the result to a dataframe for future analysis.

This is an image of the top of the csv file
[image]
This is an image of the bottom of the csv file. Note that when it switches from 'important data' to 'unimportant data' the number of columns increases, which might make programming difficult.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code. I got the column names with the **line number =5**, and data starting from **line number =8 and stopped where we encounter a blank line**.

```
import csv,pandas as pd
Space_encounter_linenum_flag=0
index_df=-1
#This flag is set when it encounters first blank line after the data values end
with open("C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/spacysample/MrX.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
     for row in csvreader:
         index_df=index_df+1
         if csvreader.line_num==5:
             #To get column names
             print("THE COLUMN NAMES IN LINE NUMBER 5 ARE...........")
             print(', '.join(row))
             df_col=pd.DataFrame(row)
         if csvreader.line_num==8:
             #To get data values
             print("**********************************************************")
             print("THE DATA VALUES STARTING FROM LINE NUMBER 8 ARE...........")
             while row[-1] is '':
                 row.pop()
             print(', '.join(row))
             df_col.append(row)
         if (csvreader.line_num>8) and max(row, key=len)=='':
             #set flag when blank line is encountered
             Space_encounter_linenum_flag=1
         if (csvreader.line_num>8 and row is not '') and (row is not '') and Space_encounter_linenum_flag!=1:
             #stop where blank line is encountered
             while row[-1] is '':
                 row.pop()
             print(', '.join(row))
             df_val=pd.DataFrame(row)
             df_col.append(df_val)
         if (csvreader.line_num>8) and Space_encounter_linenum_flag==1:
             print('Loop breaks at, line number: '+str(csvreader.line_num))
             break
```

Hope this does exactly what you want.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting some weird results with this. The results starts with a blank row and then starts printing at row 521 until the end. It is also appending something like 50 blank values on the end of each row. This is definitely closer than anything I've done though.

Also, how would you save the result to a dataframe for further analysis? Sorry, should've specified that up top.

Comment: Is the number of columns and data values equal in your CSV. Also, if possible can you share sample of your CSV data

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean but the columns amount doesn't change in the section I need, if that's what you mean. The part I don't need below my data increases the column numbers by about eight. Then there is a footer that takes up a shocking ~230 columns.


If you are asking if its a perfect square dataframe (i.e. 40x40, 500x500), it is not. There are about 21 columns with thousands of data points underneath.

Comment: Ok. updated the code to remove the trailing blank values. Check it out.

Comment: Perfect! I believe it works exactly as I need now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh quick question: once it gets to the blank row I get an error:

 line 23, in <module>
    if (csvreader.line_num>8) and max(row, key=len)=='':
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Any clues on how to fix it real quick?

Comment: Included and condition in line 28. Hope that will sort.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the error, but I'll try to figure something out. I don't want you to have to spend more time on this, as you have greatly helped me out already. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv', header=5)[7:]
# List Columns
df.columns
```

In case you don't have pandas : `pip install pandas`

`read_csv` docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: This does not get rid of the thousands of blank and unusable rows underneath my data though.

Comment: @TinyMuffin Check my answer and let me know if it doesnt work. Happy Learning!